# Custom rake task for DB: Table not found

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a custom rake task, that creates a development DB with data for various situation. The core looks like this:

```
namespace :db do
  task setup_seed: :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
  end
end
```

Everything runs fine, until `db:seed` is invoked, because it throws an error that tables does not exist. This is my `seed.rb`:

```
puts Rails.env
# => development
puts Article.count
# rake aborted!
# Mysql2::Error: Table 'app_test.articles' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `articles`
# /usr/src/app/db/seeds.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# /usr/src/app/Rakefile:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

I noticed two strange things here:

- First of all it doesn't find the table `articles` (or any table). When I halt at the beginning of my seed file and look into the DB (development), the tables are present, **but the test db is empty**
- I've printed the `Rails.env` and it returns `development`. However the failure message states that it tries to load the DB `app_test.articles` and not `app_development.articles`.

So I think this two issues are related.

Comment: You should omit a `db:migrate` task, because schema already loaded. Also add your current Rails version, `db:test:prepare` is now deprecated.

Comment: Rails version is 3.2.9. When I delete the `db:migrate` task the same error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The problem was, that the task `Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke` changes the environment to `test`, so putting that line to the bottom of the script and everything works:

```
namespace :db do
  task setup_seed: :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:create'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:schema:load'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
    Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].invoke # this one should be at the bottom
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running your rake task in development environment, but `db:test:prepare` runs in test by default. Try invoking:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup_seed
```