# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, whenever

I'm having some trouble with whenever. I created a rake task which work perfectly when I launch it myself:

```
namespace :check do
    desc "check all services"
    task :all do
       Rake::Task["fb_ping:check"].invoke
       Rake::Task["lithium_ping:check"].invoke
       Rake::Task["algolia_ping:check"].invoke
     end
end
```

but when it goes through whenever:

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
every 2.minutes do
  rake 'check:all'
end
```

I get the following return in my log:

```
    rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "services" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "services".* FROM "services"
                                 ^
: SELECT "services".* FROM "services"
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `exec_no_cache'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:585:in `execute_and_clear'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:103:in `exec_query'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:377:in `select_prepared'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:39:in `select_all'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:95:in `select_all'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:706:in `exec_queries'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:583:in `load'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:260:in `records'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:38:in `each'
/Users/Naekh/code/yoando/statuschecker/statuschecker/lib/tasks/fb_ping.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Naekh/code/yoando/statuschecker/statuschecker/lib/tasks/rake_them_all.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Naekh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I don't get how something that works independently can crash when called by whenever

// Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170922073721) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "pings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "up"
    t.integer  "service_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["service_id"], name: "index_pings_on_service_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "services", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "web_api"
    t.string   "json_path"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "pings", "services"
end
```

here is a ping check (fb_ping.rake), I used the same syntax in my other test. All of them work when I launch it manually :

```
namespace :fb_ping do
desc "New fb ping"
task check: :environment do

  Service.all.each do | s |
    if s.name == 'Facebook'
      if FacebookStatusService.status === 1
        Ping.create(up: true, service: s)
        puts  'FB service is up'
      else
        Ping.create(up: false, service: s)
        puts  'FB service is down'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

Comment: It's possible that the rake invoke method is attempting to use your test environment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125355/custom-rake-task-for-db-table-not-found

Comment: Can you post the contents of `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: @garythegoat I updated my post (thanks for your help)

Comment: @Doge can you try running `$ bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`, and then see if the error persists?

Comment: @AytanLeibowitz I thought the same and followed the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097558/pg-undefinedtable-error-relation-users-does-not-exist but it didn't worked

Comment: @garythegoat the error remains the same

Comment: @Doge could you also post the contents of `lib/tasks/fb_ping.rake`?

Comment: @garythegoat I update my post with the task

Answer (score 0):

> If a :path is not set it will default to the directory in which whenever was executed. :environment_variable will default to 'RAILS_ENV'. :environment will default to 'production'.
>   https://github.com/javan/whenever

To adjust for the environment dynamically, you will need to pass variables on the fly. https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Setting-variables-on-the-fly

As a first test, try to hardcode your current environment, I'm assuming development in the example below:

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
every 2.minutes do
  rake 'check:all', :environment => 'development'
end
```

Comment: I just tried and I had the same message in my error log. I run a check to see if I was not in test instead of development in the console (Rails.env) and I'm in development

Comment: I apologize if this seems silly, but have you tried restarting your rails console?

Comment: Yes I did :)
That's not silly at all. I appreciate the help